# Install 32-bit version of Oracle JDK 7 on a 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 32-bit, jdk, oracle

I am using https://askubuntu.com/a/61873/23678 to install the 64-bit version of Oracle JDK 7 under Ubuntu 64-bit. Is there a way to tweak this mechanism to install the 32-bit JDK instead?

If not, how do I install a 32-bit Oracle JDK 7 under Ubuntu 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the second answer there would default to installing 64-bit Java (and it is a third-party tool so I doubt you could easily do much about that).

Just use the first answer with the 32-bit Oracle JDK 7. It is complicated, but it is the official Oracle way of doing it. You just need to make sure it stays updated manually (i.e. download and reinstall when a new release is out).

Comment: Best answer so far. I'll wait for alternatives, otherwise mark it as accepted. Thank you :)